# Supremum family of measurable functions is not measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ be an uncountable family of measurable functions $f_i:X \to \mathbb{R}$. Show that functions defined by,
$$ h(x)=\inf\{ f_i(x) : i \in I \} \:\:\: \text{for each }x \in X$$
and
$$ g(x)=\sup\{ f_i(x) : i \in I \} \:\:\: \text{for each }x \in X$$
are not measurable in generality.

The idea

let's take a non-measurable set E, then
$\mathbb{1}_{ \{e\} }$ where $e \in E$, indicator functions are measurable. However
$$ g(x)= \mathbb{1}_ {E} $$ is not measurable but I do not know why.

For $h(x)$ we just take $-\mathbb{1}_{ \{e\} }$.

Is there any possibility that someone will clarify the problem?

Comment: Let $E$ be a non-measurable set. For each $e \in E$, let $f_e = \mathbb{1}_{ \{e\} }$, the indicator function of the singleton $\{e\}$. Then, let, foe each $x \in X$, 
$$ g(x)=\sup\{ f_e(x) : e \in E \}  = \mathbb{1}_{ E }(x)$$
It means $g = \mathbb{1}_{ E }$. But then $g$ is not measurable, because $g^{-1}(\{1\})= E$ and $E$ is non-measurable. 

For $h$ just take $f_e = -\mathbb{1}_{ \{e\} }$, and then $h= -\mathbb{1}_{ E }$, which is not measurable, because $h^{-1}(\{-1\})= E$ and $E$ is non-measurable.

Comment: But why $f_e $ is measurable. I guess we have $f_e^{-1}({1})=e $ and $f_e^{-1}({0})$ is anything else than e? So due to it we have measurability?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.